# Github Workflow: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using a github workflow to automate some actions for AWS. I haven't changed anything for a while as the script has been working nicely for me. Recently I've been getting this error: `Unable to process file command 'env' successfully` whenever the workflow runs. I've got no idea why this is happening. Any help or pointers would greatly appreciated. Thanks. Here's the workflow which is outputting the error:

```
- name: "Get AWS Resource values"
  id: get_aws_resource_values
  env:
    SHARED_RESOURCES_ENV: ${{ github.event.inputs.shared_resources_workspace }}
  run: |
    BASTION_INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
     --filters "Name=tag:env,Values=$SHARED_RESOURCES_ENV" \
     --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" \
     --output text)

    RDS_ENDPOINT=$(aws rds describe-db-instances \
      --db-instance-identifier $SHARED_RESOURCES_ENV-rds \
      --query "DBInstances[0].Endpoint.Address" \
      --output text)

    echo "rds_endpoint=$RDS_ENDPOINT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "bastion_instance_id=$BASTION_INSTANCE_ID" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Any chance there might be spaces in the env variables?

Comment: Where would i find the env variables?

Comment: what is the value of $SHARED_RESOURCES_ENV for example. I wonder if spaces in this variable might cause problems ...

Answer (score 0):

From the RDS endpoint query expression (`Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId`) in your aws cli command, it seems you expect a multiline string. It could also be that before you started to receive this error the command was producing a single line string, and that changed at some point.

In GitHub actions, multiline strings for environment variables and outputs need to be created with a [different syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings).

For the RDS endpoint you should set the environment variable like this:

```
echo "rds_endpoint<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
echo "$RDS_ENDPOINT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I guess that the bastion instance id will not be a problem since it's a single line string.